# How to implement PKCE for OpenId Connect in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, openid-connect, pkce

Please help, I look around on Internet for almost 2 days but found no solution.
Currently, I use oidc-client to implement SSO login for my Nuxtjs App (Nuxt 2). Everything work ok. But due to change of rules, we need to add PKCE to this authentication. I have already tried @nuxtjs/auth-next and use scheme openIDConnect (https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/openIDConnect) but it doesn't work at all.
It keeps showing 2 errors:

```
1. [AUTH] [OPENID CONNECT] Invalid configuration. Value of scheme option scope is not supported by scopes_supported of by Authorization Server.
```

**=> I confirm that All scopes are valid**

```
2. TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'common')
    at RequestHandler._requestHasAuthorizationHeader (runtime.mjs:951:29)
    at eval (runtime.mjs:928:28)
```

**=> Really Don't know why this error happens**

**Below is my old code that works fine if no need PKCE:**

```
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings } from 'oidc-client'

export const oidcSettings: UserManagerSettings = {
  authority: process.env.SSO_API,
  client_id: process.env.SSO_CLIENT_ID,
  redirect_uri: process.env.SSO_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI,
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid offline email profile offline_access',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: process.env.SSO_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
}

export const oidcUser = new UserManager(oidcSettings)

export const loginWithOidc = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await oidcUser.signinRedirect()
    return response
  } catch (error: any) {
    return error
  }
}
```

**And this is code inside nuxt.config.js. I am sure that the configuration endpoints is correct and no problem with this because it work fine with my old code.**

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      oidcmock: {
        scheme: 'openIDConnect',
        responseType: 'code',
        clientId: 'fpl-web-client',
        scope: 'openid offline email profile offline_access',
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        logoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:80',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:80/login/sso/callback',
        endpoints: {
          configuration: process.env.ENDPOINTS_CONFIG,
        },
        codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
      },
    },
  },
```

Hope to receive any advice soons.
**Merry Christmas**